# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: spring-mvc, heap-memory

i'm usning Maven 3.0,When i ran the dal test class getting follow exception.If i removed some of entity dependency from pom it's working fine.How to solve this.
My dal pom is like this.

### For Sample i placed only 3.

jav.nes.model.Ward
                jav.nes.model.Patient
                jav.nes.model.Doctor

Internal Error (c1_Optimizer.cpp:271), pid=4932, tid=7252

## guarantee(x_compare_res != Constant::not_comparable) failed: incomparable constants in IfOp

#

## JRE version: 6.0_35-b10

## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.10-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )

## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

## http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x019d2000):  JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7252, stack(0x65fa0000,0x65ff0000)]

Stack: [0x65fa0000,0x65ff0000],  sp=0x65fef824,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x133d0a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12e91c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2059b2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x206686]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f0867]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f08b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f0dbb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2050c0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x205181]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f16aa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e38de]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e3ee5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e3fec]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e413f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e4394]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3dc7d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3e7af]
V  [jvm.dll+0x119334]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14158c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ed5c]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637eb]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637be]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xc2

Current CompileTask:
C1:   3274 818      org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.setType(Lorg/hibernate/reflection/XProperty;Lorg/hibernate/reflection/XClass;)V (933 bytes)

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x019e7c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8124, stack(0x65ff0000,0x66040000)]
=>0x019d2000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7252, stack(0x65fa0000,0x65ff0000)]
  0x019d1000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6284, stack(0x65f50000,0x65fa0000)]
  0x019ce000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1324, stack(0x65f00000,0x65f50000)]
  0x019a0c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7500, stack(0x65eb0000,0x65f00000)]
  0x0199c000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4408, stack(0x65e60000,0x65eb0000)]
  0x0028a000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=5956, stack(0x00290000,0x002e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01998000 VMThread [stack: 0x65e10000,0x65e60000] [id=8004]
  0x01a04800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x66040000,0x66090000] [id=2728]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 314560K, used 83886K [0x03a90000, 0x18fe0000, 0x18fe0000)
  eden space 279616K,  30% used [0x03a90000, 0x08c7b8f8, 0x14ba0000)
  from space 34944K,   0% used [0x14ba0000, 0x14ba0000, 0x16dc0000)
  to   space 34944K,   0% used [0x16dc0000, 0x16dc0000, 0x18fe0000)
 tenured generation   total 699072K, used 0K [0x18fe0000, 0x43a90000, 0x43a90000)
   the space 699072K,   0% used [0x18fe0000, 0x18fe0000, 0x18fe0200, 0x43a90000)
 compacting perm gen  total 14336K, used 14283K [0x43a90000, 0x44890000, 0x63a90000)
   the space 14336K,  99% used [0x43a90000, 0x44883300, 0x44883400, 0x44890000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x01a10000, 0x01c38000, 0x03a10000)
 total_blobs=1014 nmethods=854 adapters=95 free_code_cache=31301760 largest_free_block=384

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to a newer JRE and make sure your system memory is working fine. It looks like either a hardware fault or a bug in the Hotspot/JVM.
Java 6 is alread end-of-life, so consider taking steps toward Java 7 (which includes a newer JVM and many many bugfixes.)